# PHP: Get Page URL minus arguments

Tags: php, apache

How do i get the URL of the current page minus all of the get arguments (?blah=2&blah4=90...)
I know i can get the full URL with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] but i was wondering if there was something that more fit my needs.

Or should i just do strpos ? and substr to chop of the arguments? ( i imagine that a $_SERVER var would be more efficient - if one exists)

Thanks

Comment: May want to look in to php's parse_url.  That should do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URL']`

Sometimes answers are easy :) I found the solution here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php by CTRL+F'ing for "query".

**EDIT**

As matchu said in the comments, not all servers support REQUEST_URL. In that case I would use the much less elegant `strtok($url, '?');`.

Comment: The fact that this is only in the comments make me nervous. It'll probably work as expected, but maybe not in all environments.

Comment: Hah, better than mine. +1. Guess I'll just get rid of my answer.

Comment: Searching around a bit, it looks Apache includes `REQUEST_URL`, but other servers, such as lighttpd, do not, as [this bug report on a PHP framework](http://code.google.com/p/atomikframework/issues/detail?id=11) indicates.

Comment: @Matchu: I posed an alternative solution, just in case :)

Comment: Thanks! I didnt know that strtok() existed!

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URL']
```

should do the trick...

It's listed here in the comments:
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Don't know why it isn't in the doco?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [parse_url function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and then concat the parts you need(scheme, host, port, user, pass and path)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, is pretty simple:

```
$url = explode("?",$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]);
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/" . $url[0];
```

With exploding the URL you will have in `$url[0]` the "first part" and in `$url[1]` all the arguments.